# Create observable model for databinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, model

I have a models that are used for serializing data to xml.

Ex

```
public class File : IFile
    {

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ObjectId;


        public string OriginalFileName { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }


        public static explicit operator File(FileItem a)  // explicit File to FileItem conversion operator
        {
            File b = new File();  // explicit conversion

            b.ObjectId = a.ObjectId;
            b.Note = a.Note;
            b.FileName = a.FileName;
            b.OriginalFileName = a.OriginalFileName;
            b.Size = a.Size;

            return b;
        }
    }
```

These classes are mainly used for reading and saving xml documents inside a worddocument. 
Inside the main application i need data to be observable so in this case i use prism and the classes inherits from Notificationobject.

Ex

```
public class FileItem : NotificationObject, IFile
    {

        public FileItem()
        {

        }

        public static explicit operator FileItem(File a)  // explicit File to FileItem conversion operator
        {
            FileItem d = new FileItem();  // explicit conversion

            d.ObjectId = a.ObjectId;
            d.Note = a.Note;
            d.FileName = a.FileName;
            d.OriginalFileName = a.OriginalFileName;
            d.Size = a.Size;

            return d;
        }



        private string _objectid;
        public string ObjectId
        {
            get { return _objectid; }
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_objectid))
                {
                    _objectid = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ObjectId);
                }
.................
```

So what i do is that i first read xml files into the File class and then i need to convert it into FileItem class and when i want to save it back to xml i need to do the reverse conversion again. This seems a little bit unessesary to me. I could think of a solution where i serialize directly into FileItem but i need to keep File simple as it is defined in a assembly that is used by other components that does not need notificationobject and where prism assemblies will not be installed.

Any ideas on how to simplify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) to automatically map from one object to the other.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, i have read a little about i and got it with Nuget. I havent figured out on how to get recent samples thoug but it seems to be what im looking for